# Responsive menu not working when jquery.mobile is active

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm going through the [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html), and I'm not sure how to handle the page loading.

I have a web page, and I'd like to have a swipeable menu when I'm on a mobile view (<767px). I loaded the jquery.mobile.js, and with a simple

```
        $(window).on('swiperight', function(){
            $menu_toggle.addClass('mobile_open');
            $navigation.fadeIn().animate({width: '80%'},250);
        });

        $(window).on('swipeleft', function(){
            $menu_toggle.removeClass('mobile_open');
            $navigation.animate({width: '0' },250).fadeOut();
        });
```

I am displaying the menu. Menu toggle is the classic 'hamburger' menu that also works if you click on it.

The swipe works, when I wipe to right, menu opens, and when I swipe left the menu closes.

However the problem is that when I click on a link in a menu, it won't take me to that page. What option, and where, should I set to enable this behavior?

Or is there some other way of using the swipe motion to open the menu, without jquery.mobile.js?

EDIT:

Added fiddle, although I cannot see how this will help, becuase you cannot navigate here, but the animation works

http://jsfiddle.net/zj0hvbba/

Comment: can you make jsfiddle?

Comment: jQuery mobile by default changes the way page navigation works. When linking to another page, it looks for the first DIV with data-role="page" and tries to load that via ajax. If all you are looking for is swipe events, you would be better off using a dedicated touch library like hammer js as jQuery Mobile is an entire framework.

Comment: Yeah, basically I only need swipe events (I'm not building an app, just a website), and the swipe gesture is more a feature than anything. I'll look into the hammer.js. Thanks :)

Comment: hammer.js did the trick! Thanks ezanker :)